# Post Templates and Post ID's

Tags: posts, templates

I am trying to make use of the Single template for single posts ( I have a custom one). But for some reason my posts get overridden instead of displaying new data.

This is the setup I have right now

```
<div class="details">
<?php global $post;
 $category_id=get_the_category($post->ID);

$announcements = new WP_Query(); 
$announcements->query('showposts=1&cat=$category_id');
while ( $announcements->have_posts() ) :  $announcements->the_post(); ?>  

    <p><strong>Published by:<span itemprop="publisher"><?php echo 
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Publisher','true');?></strong></p>

<?php endwhile;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why anyway are you doing a second query.

Answer (score 1):

> But for some reason my posts get overridden instead of displaying new
>   data.

The problem is here: `$announcements->query('showposts=1&cat=$category_id');`

You are trying to use a variable inside a single quote string. [Variables do not expand inside single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) so instead of asking for `cat=1`, or `cat=2`, you are literally asking for `cat=$category_id`-- just like that, spelled out in full.

What you need instead are double quotes: `$announcements->query("showposts=1&cat=$category_id");`. Variables do expand in double quote.

Or better, an array-- far more readable and maintainable:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
  'cat' => $category_id,
);
```

Note: `showposts` is deprecated. Use `posts_per_page`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Pass arguments into the new Object like so.

```
$category_id = get_the_category( $post->ID );

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'category'       => $category_id
);

$announcements = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This page should shine some light on your code for you, I think you've got a few typo's within it and how you call the loop is in the slightly wrong order. [`WP_Query` in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Answer (score 0):

I tried that, but it still overrides for instance

```
the_title(), get_post_meta($post->ID, 'key', 'true'), the_post_thumbnail(),
```

and pretty much all of them gets overriden(What I mean is when I make two posts using the same template, the fields, titles and images get overridden.) Here is how I did it:

```
<?php
$category_id = get_the_category( $post->ID ); $args =  

array('posts_per_page' => 1, 'category' => $category_id); $announcements = 
new WP_Query( $args );

while($announcements->have_posts()): $announcements->the_post();

?>
<div class="cover"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
<p><strong><span itemprop="title"><?php the_title();?></span></strong></p>
</div>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Answer for @kaiser below.

Comment: Answer are not threaded, @Johnny.